# how to select Google result item in Chrome only use keyboard

Tags: google-chrome

I get addicted to use shortcut keys rather that mouse during development because that makes things done really fast.

When I Google somthing in Chrome, I always use CTRL + T, CTRL +W, CTRL + L, CTRL (+ SHIFT) + TAB etc., but that is not fast enough for me, and I do not want to stop to use mouse to click the searching result, that is too slows. So I wonder if there is any shortcut key to handle that? Any advice from you will be greatly appreciate.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am using the vimium extension for chrome. Justhit "f" and each link in the page gets an overlay, which displays the corresponding shortcut key for the link.